# Java object layout and static fields

Tags: java, java-memory-model, object-layout, jol

The [JOL](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) tool gives ability to count object's memory layout.

I've noticed, that static fields do not participate in calculating, for example:

```
public class Foo {

    private static final int i = 1;

    private char value;

    public Foo(char value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

then,

```
System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseClass(Foo.class).toPrintable());
```

gives the following output:

```
com.kishlaly.Foo object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE  TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
      0    12       (object header)                N/A
     12     2  char Foo.value                      N/A
     14     2       (loss due to the next object alignment)
Instance size: 16 bytes (estimated, the sample instance is not available)
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 2 bytes external = 2 bytes total
```

Where does *private static final int* lies in memory?

Comment: `i` clearly isn't stored in object instances (that's what `static` means).  Where exactly it gets placed depends on the JVM. (I don't know more details off the top of my head, hence why I'm commenting rather than answering.)

Comment: yes, the question is where do statics reside =)

Answer (score 3):

The tool is giving the memory layout of an object on the heap. The static content is in the PermGen section of the memory & it's on the JVM implementation whether it is included in the heap or not.

Your tool provided the memory layout of the object, whereas static variable is a class level variable it will be always in the permanent generation section of memory & would not be included in this layout.